# Time Difference between two time values giving wrong output in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have converted 6 digits numeric value to timestamp in format hh:mm:ss, when I am subtracting one timestamp with other it is giving me wrong output. For example, if i am subtracting 10:57:01 with 10:59:01 its giving correct value which is :02:00 min but when I am subtracting 10:59:01 from 11:00:01 it is giving output :41:00 that has to be 1 min i.e :01:00

```
10:57:01    10:59:01    :02:00 (B2-A2)
10:59:01    11:00:01    :41:00 (B3-A3)
```

The custom time format to convert the number to time that I have used is #":"00:"00

[image]

Comment: 6 digits values are 100001,.. 102029, ..105956..112014,,,so on..

Comment: They are the labels of files with numbers with 6 digits that are actually representing the time value, which i have entered in cells using macro now i have to calculate the time difference between two values in columns after converting them into time format.

Comment: then you are not converting the number to a time but are applying a mask of `##:##:##` to a number

Comment: So, in that case how can i convert them in actual time?

Comment: Well that depends on a lot of things.  how the data is being entered, do you want helper columns,...

Comment: i have used this formula but still having the same problem while difference =1*TEXT(B2,"00\:00\:00")... yes helper columns will be okay for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then you are not converting the number to a time but are applying a mask of `##\:##\:##` to a number

[image]

What that means is `10:00:01` is not being seen by excel as 10 hours 00 minutes and 01 seconds but `100,001` with a different mask.  So when you write `11:00:01-10:59:01` excel sees it as `110,001 - 105,901` which equals `4100`

If you do not want to change the inputs, which is the better method, you can parse the value in the cells and subtract them:

```
=TEXT(B2,"##\:##\:##")-TEXT(A2,"##\:##\:##")
```

And format the result as `hh:mm:ss`

[image]

Comment: Scott you have been again a great help, thank you so much for giving your time and helping me out